# Angular Web Worker accessing shared functions?

Tags: angular, web-worker

I'm migrating some processing into web workers in an angular app. I have some shared methods in a `helpers.ts` file. I would like to be able to access those methods in the worker, as well as in my app. Everything works if I simply duplicate the methods, but some are quite involved and seems like an anti-pattern to have to maintain 2 identical methods. Is `importScripts()` the way to go about this? I tried moving the methods into the webworker file and then importing that file but angular complains if it's not a service.

helpers.ts (imports some type declarations and external libraries):

```
import { Asset } from "../models/object.model";
.....
import * as clone from 'clone';

export function magic(needle: string, haystack: string){
  let theArray = needle.toLowerCase().split('')
  theArray.forEach((e,i,a) => a[i] = a[i].replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.\\^$|,#\s]/g, "\\$&"));
  let re = RegExp(`.*${theArray.join('.*')}.*`);
  return !!haystack.toLowerCase().match(re)
} 

export function magicObjects(needle: string, haystack: string[]) {
  var output: string[] = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
    if(magic(needle, haystack[i])) {
      output.push(haystack[i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
//etc etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

can you not just do something like this

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
import { magic} from './helper.ts';

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
    postMessage(magic(data));
});
```

you would have to make the method parameters into an object instead though.